# How to write unit tests in Kafka go

Tags: unit-testing, go, apache-kafka

What is the correct way to write unit tests for Kafka in golang?

In java, for Kafka streams we have Kafka stream test until that simplifies writing test cases.

However, I am not able to find similar things in Kafka for golang.

There are a few nice articles on how to use docker containers to bring up Kafka and test the E2E flow. But I am really looking for unit tests with mock servers.

I am using confluent kafka go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unclear what library you're looking for. Sarama has a mocks package that can be used https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/tree/main/mocks

You don't mock servers, only data passing between clients

Comment: I am using confluent kafka go

Comment: @AvishekBhattacharya Looking at the repo itself, it seems to be tested using Docker beyond the regular `consumer_test.go` file, for example

Comment: Yes, they are testing with the docker in the integ test